# Where do Logic Gates Get the First 0 or 1?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I've been thinking about playing around with some logic gates on breadboards... But where do I get the first 0 or 1? I could use a regulator,but is there a better solution? or would a logic gate just automatically interpret no voltage/current as a 0?

Comment: Pull-up or pull-down resistor. Or a switch that directly ties to +V or GND. Or hardwire to +V or GND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CMOS logic gate won't interpret no voltage (i.e. an open circuit) as a 0 or a 1. This is because there is (ideally) no leakage path between the input and ground or the supply. Any charge that is on the input would (ideally) remain there and not be well controlled.

TTL logic gates *do* have an input pull-ups and an open circuit unit will be a stable '1'; although it would still be good practice to tie an unused input to supply (if a 1 is desired).

On your breadboard, you may be using a regulator to supply the logic gates, but if these are CMOS (e.g. CD4xxx series) gates, a 6 V supply will work without a regulator. What is important is that the interconnected gates are all operating from the same supply voltage (and same ground).

Comment: I'm pretty sure some of the 74 series pull down, not always up.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199922/why-led-is-on-when-there-is-no-input-at-terminal-1-2-for-7432-ic

Comment: I'm not sure what you're meaning to say with that. I'm referring to some of the ones that use different architecture, like the 74LS series pulls up but I *think* the 74F series might pull down? I don't remember in detail. Of course the 74(A)(H)C(T) series are all CMOS and have floating inputs.

Comment: @Hearth - I'm not aware of any TTL, LS, or S logic families that had pulldownsn the input.